# Scala partial function syntax

Tags: scala

There are two ways (that I know of) to create a `PartialFunction` in scala.  The most common is

```
def common: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 1 => "one"
  case 2 => "two"
  case n if n % 2 == 0 => "large even number"
}
```

The less common one is define the methods on `PartialFunction`:

```
class LessCommon extends PartialFunction[Double, Double]:
  override def isDefinedAt(x: Double): Boolean = x >= 0 || x == -3
  override def apply(x: Double): Double = 
     x match 
       case positive if positive >= 0: Math.sqrt(positive)
       case -3: 17.0 // don't ask
```

The common case is fairly clearly a shorthand that lets you drop the `match` and the method declarations and skip duplicating the cases in `isDefinedAt`.  Is there any way to use the shorter version when you want to something in all of the cases?

Examples that I have run into are logging the inputs (`logger.info("x: {}", x); x match { ... }`) or a function called for side effects that would always return the same value (`x match { ... }; Actions.Continue`).

Comment: Use `andThen` or `compose`?